# How to change various attributes of an object in MongodB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, object, mongoose, backend

I'm having difficulty changing multiple attributes of an object at the same time. My model is below:

```
const Schema = new Schema({
    main_object:{
      object1:{
       0: {
          logic: false,
          text: "Hi"},
       1: {
          logic: false,
          text: "wow"},
       2: {
          logic: false,
          text: "Hello"},
       3: {
          logic: false,
          text: "sad"},
       },
      object2:{
       0: false,
       1: false,
       2: false
       },
}});
```

and inside my controller, I have the update function:

```
async my_update(req, res) {
        const filter = { my_filter: req.body.my_filter };
        const input = [0 2]; //This entry may vary.
        const mydata = await MyModel.updateOne(filter,
            {
           // I know the code below is not suitable.
          for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
         $set: {"main_object.object1.input[i].logic":true};
              }
            // I want the line above to do dynamically:
            // $set: {"main_object.object1.0.logic":true}
            // $set: {"main_object.object1.2.logic":true}
            });
        return res.json(mydata)
    },
```

Comment: if you change your model to an array of booleans rather than a complex object with fields called 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. you will be more happy.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Schema = new Schema({
    main_object:{
      object1:[],
      object2:[]
}});
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. However, I would like to solve this problem without using an array, since this answer limits me to more complex problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element to be selected dynamically, build the fieldname string dynamically.

```
$set: {"main_object.object1."+i+".logic":true}
```

Then build the update portion of the command by mapping over the input array:

```
input.map( function(i) { return {"$set": {"main_object.object1."+i+".logic":true}})
```

Comment: Inside the code, it was not possible to apply your suggestion. Specifically in this part "main_object.object1."+i+".logic":true. However, I got an idea with your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside my controller:

```
async my_update(req, res) {
        const filter = { my_filter: req.body.my_filter };
        const input = [0, 2]; //Variable input
        const field = input.map((item, i) => [`main_object.object1.${item}.logic`, true]); // Create the fields dynamically. Output: list of key-value pairs.
        const update_operator = {$set: Object.fromEntries(field) } // Transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.
        const mydata = await MyModel.updateOne(filter,
            update_operator,
            { upsert: true });
        return res.json(mydata)
    },
```